# Has anyone gotten much use out of Angular 2 in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, angularjs, angular2

Has anyone gotten much use out of Angular 2 in SharePoint?

I'm curious about the benefits of using Angular 2 in SP (onPrem), but it seems the setup time makes it not worth it vs Angular 1.

Anyone care to weigh in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS (Angular v1) and all versions after (it is now Angular v4 but we call it Angular) are apples and oranges,

Yes everything ^2 requires a different toolchain (not unlike SharePoint Fx) but it is also a different language.

So AngularJS (v1) and Angular (v2,v3,v4,v...) are both tools in you toolbox you use for what they are best at.

> *Would you hire a builder for a large job who only brought one hammer with him?*

For simple SPAs I use AngularJS because it is quick to get started with (with also look at Vue.JS then!) and doesn't require a whole built; instant results in the Browser with a CEWP

And for more complex SPAs it is Angular, or Polymer, or React (which Microsoft has chosen for SPFx)

and more and more just plain vanilla ES6, now modern Browsers support WebComponents

React  is the jQuery of 2018, half the technologies Facebook developed are now IN the Browser engine. apart from "*we have to continue with what we started 2 years ago*" there hardly is a use-case for React anymore.
And don't forget to let your Legal team read and agree with that BSD license Facebook put on it... React is NOT Open-Source!!!

Angular still is cool, but it more and more feels you need to do all or nothing

I like VueJS,

**WebComponents**

I love https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction

Ofcourse we're still waiting for Microsoft to implement a W3C standard:
http://jonrimmer.github.io/are-we-componentized-yet/
So need a polyfill (what Polymer is)

fun fact: Microsoft implemented part of the spec in IE5.5 (1999)
Then removed it in IE10

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Have you made use of Angular 2 or primarily AngularJs (pre-2) in SP?

Comment: (1) AngularJS and VueJS because it is so much easier for other team-members to make enhancements. (2) Angular when (and only IF!) there are more team-members who have the required skillset.